# Audio momentarily dropping

Tags: windows-7, audio, windows-media-player

I keep getting the following error message in Windows Media Player

> An audio device was disconnected or reconfigured. Verify that the audio device is connected.

the weird thing is, if I immediately try to play something after closing the message, it works.

I thought it might be a dodgy connection somewhere, but I checked everything and it's still happening. I've also experienced a similar issue with YouTube, the audio will suddenly stop and I have to refresh the page to get it back.

This started happening in the past couple of days, but I can't think of anything I've done that could have caused it (not messed around with audio drivers or anything). Audio is coming straight from my AMD Radeon HD 6950 (I don't have a separate sound card) via HDMI into my monitor.

**Anyone know what could be causing me to momentarily lose audio?**

Comment: Audio hardware details?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this could be caused by an audio jack from a headphone that's not properly plugged in.

Or if it's software related, using System Restore to roll back the system to an earlier state could help.